# How can i define my own event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i define my own event in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define and attach your own custom events with [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
// make myObject listen for myFancyEvent
$('#myobject').bind('myFancyEvent', function(){
  alert('Yow!');
});
```

...then [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) them directly:

```
$('#myobject').trigger('myFancyEvent');
```

...or mixed in with other event handlers:

```
$('#myobject').click( function(){
  doSomething();
  $(this).trigger('myFancyEvent');
});
```

You shouldn't have trouble finding a lot of information on the subject. [This article](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/04/custom-events-in-jquery-open-doors-to-complex-behaviors/) is a couple of years old, but still a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [link](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/).

Here are some code snippet from the article above.

You can trigger custom events on any DOM object of your choosing using jQuery. Just trigger it using the following code:

```
$("#myelement").trigger('fuelified');
```

You can subscribe to that event using either bind or live functions in jQuery:

```
$("#myelement").bind('fuelified',function(e){ ... });
$(".cool_elements").live('fuelified',function(e){ ... });
```

You can even pass additional data about the event when triggering it and reference it on the listeners end:

```
$("#myelement").trigger('fuelified',{ custom: false });
$("#myelement").bind('fuelified',function(e,data){ if(data.custom) ... });
```

The element the trigger has been called on, is available to listener’s callback function as the variable this.

Comment: +1 if you expand your answer to perhaps include some code from the article with a link to it for more info...otherwise if the link changes, the answer isn't that brilliant

Answer (score 1):

You can throw events like this:

```
$("#element").trigger("your.event", [ 'Pamela', 'Anderson' ] );
```

Note that extra parameters should be passed as an array.

How to listen for events:

```
$("#element").bind("your.event", function(event, firstName, lastName) { 
    // Callback
});
```

The "#element" selector can be substituted with document if the event isn't specific for a particular dom node.

jQuery documentation:
[Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
[Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)